# Missing conversation handle in Service Broker

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016, service-broker

I'm creating a conversation for my queue on Service Broker (SQL 2016) using the following :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @NotificationDialog 
FROM SERVICE ChangeNotifications 
TO SERVICE 'ChangeNotifications' 
ON CONTRACT [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] 
WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF; 

-- Send the message 
-- 
SEND ON CONVERSATION @NotificationDialog  
MESSAGE TYPE [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification] (@Message)      

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I'm receiving the message in a windows service using the following code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR ( RECEIVE * FROM dbo.NotificationsQueue);", cnn))
{
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cnn.Open();

    // Execute the command - we will wait here until a new entry appears in the Notification Queue
    //
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Get the message text from the reader
    //
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Get the message body text and convert into a legible format
        //
        messageText = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("message_body"));
        messtype = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("message_type_name"));
        convhandle = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("conversation_handle"));
    }

    reader.Close();
    reader = null;

    if (messtype == @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog" ||
        messtype == @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error" ||
        messtype == @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification" )
    {
        var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("end conversation '" + convhandle.ToString() + "'", cnn);

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd2.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When the code tries to execute the end conversation, I get an error 'The conversation handle is not found.'. If I search sys.conversation_endpoints for the handle it doesn't exist either. I'm not actively ending the conversation anywhere.
Why is there no record for it?

Comment: Are you running a Stored Procedure?  The use following : cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: @jdweng, the code is clearly not executing a stored procedure.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the code you posted that would case this error, although I recommend parameterizing the `END CONVERSATION` query and surrounding in a `using` block like the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of faffing about I found a solution to my problem. First off the sql side needed an end conversation in it:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @NotificationDialog 
FROM SERVICE ChangeNotifications 
TO SERVICE 'ChangeNotifications' 
ON CONTRACT [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] 
WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF; 

-- Send the message 
-- 
SEND ON CONVERSATION @NotificationDialog  
MESSAGE TYPE [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification] (@Message)      

-- ** Was missing from original code **
--
END CONVERSATION @NotificationDialog;   

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Then I needed to modify the receiving code to handle the fact that I get an extra End Dialog message in the queue when I call the end conversation:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MetricBroadcast.Properties.Settings.TargetConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    string messtype = "";
    Guid convhandle = new Guid();

    cnn.Open();
    trans = cnn.BeginTransaction("queuetrans");

    // Create the command to monitor the Notifications Queue
    //
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR ( RECEIVE * FROM dbo.NotificationsQueue);", cnn, trans))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        // Execute the command - we will wait here until a new entry appears in the Notification Queue
        //
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Get the message text from the reader
        //
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Get the message body text and convert into a legible format
            //
            messtype = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("message_type_name"));
            convhandle = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("conversation_handle"));

            if (messtype == @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification")
            {
                messageText = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetString(reader.GetSqlBinary(reader.GetOrdinal("message_body")).Value);
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
        reader = null;


        if (messtype == @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog" ||
            messtype == @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error")
        {
            var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("end conversation '" + convhandle.ToString() + "'", cnn, trans);

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd2.Dispose();
        }

        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Now that its working nicely, I'll probably do as Dan Guzman suggests and parameterise the end conversation query and surround it in a using query.

Hope this helps anyone else having issues.

Rob